# Creating a public profile and custom URL in PHP

Tags: php, url-rewriting, content-management-system, user-profile

I'm looking to create a user admin area and public profile page with custom URL in PHP. I have found a great tutorial on users creating their own private admin area. However, I'm struggling to find further guidance on the following:

1. Creating a public custom URL (such as as website.com/username) based on what the user requested on signup.
2. Using that custom URL to display public profile page with selected information the user entered into their private admin area.

I know this is bread and butter stuff but I'm leaning PHP so any guidance and best practices at this stage are very welcome.

Thanks, Jack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

1. Use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (assuming you have an Apache server) to forward all `domain.com/abcde` requests that don't match an existing file or directory (see `-f` condition) to `domain.com/user.php?name=abcde`
2. In `user.php`, get all the data based on the user-chosen name from the database and display it, display an error message if no user is found.

Comment: Easy when you know - Thats exactly what I needed: a simple workflow to get me started.